# Configure pdf for double-sided print using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf v4.0 package (mPDF wrapper)

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

I'm using niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf laravel package which is a mPDF wrapper to print a report.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('report.weekly', compact('data'), [], ['format' => 'A4-L']);
return $pdf->stream($report_name.'.pdf');
```

This report has several lists(tables) and being a long document, we print it double-sided. There is a `<pagebreak>` tag before new list is added to the document in blade file like this:

```
</table> // End of list/table

<pagebreak>

<table> // Start of next list/table
```

Problem is I want the lists to be starting at odd pages. It is handy in double-sided print as some lists are 2-3 pages long so all the lists will be on the front when looking/shuffling the pages.

What I tried without luck:

```
<pagebreak type="o">
<pagebreak type="next-odd">
```

I also found upon searching that adding `mirrorMargins => 1` will do the trick, but not working for me:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('report.weekly', compact('data'), [], ['format' => 'A4-L', 'mirrorMargins' => 1]);
```